# How to break a dynamic(changing) string into two different parts?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I had a field from the API response which gives me data like "Welcome Name" or it can be "Welcome back Name". Name can be any combination of firstName middleName lastName. I want to break it into two parts,

1 - "Welcome" or "Welcome back" (as per the response from API)

2 - "Name"

```
for example :

if data is "Welcome Aman Pratap Singh" break into 1-"Welcome" 2-"Aman Pratap Singh" 

if data is "Welcome back ABCDE PQR XYZ" break into 1-"Welcome back" 2-"ABCDE PQR XYZ"

if data is "Welcome ABC XYZ" break into 1-"Welcome" 2-"ABC XYZ"

if data is "Welcome back ABC XYZ" break into 1-"Welcome back" 2-"ABC XYZ"

if data is  "Welcome ABCDE" break into 1-"Welcome" 2-"ABCDE"

if data is  "Welcome back ABCDE" break into 1-"Welcome back" 2-"ABCDE"
```

Comment: What happens if my name is `back`?

Comment: If the name is Back and response is like "Welcome Back" then 1- "Welcome" 2-"Back" or if response is "Welcome back Back" then 1-"Welcome back" 2- "Back" , although I think this will be the rare case of the data that I'm getting in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex ought to be able to do this:

```js
let splitWelcomeStr = str => {
  let match = str.match(/^(Welcome( back)?) (.+)$/);
  if (!match) throw new Error('Invalid welcome string provided');
  return { welcome: match[1], name: match[3] };
};

console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome John'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome John Doe'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome John H. Doe'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome back John'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome back John Doe'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome back John H. Doe'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome back'));
console.log(splitWelcomeStr('Welcome back back'));
```

A breakdown of the regex used:

```
^(Welcome( back)?) (.+)$

^                         Match the start of the sequence
 (               )        Create a result at index 1
  Welcome                 The string "Welcome"
         (     )?         An optional string (and a result at index 2)
           back           The string " back" (prefixed with a space!)
                   (.+)   A space followed by  match at index 3 for any further characters
                       $  Match the end of the sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the the `split()` method in javascript to 'split' your string into an array of strings.

example:

```
var str = "hello sir";
var arrayOfStrings = str.split(" ");
```

so now `arrayOfStrings[0]` contains "hello" in it,
and `arrayOfStrings[1]` contains "sir" in it